# Find the expected value of a dice sum

Tags: probability, dice

If fair dodecahedron is rolled until at least $k$($k$ is fixed between 2 and 12) is gotten, and $X$ is the sum of all numbers appeared until the last time, what is $E(X)$?

Comment: What is the probability that it will take m rolls? What is the distribution of X over those m rolls?

Comment: Once $k$ or greater than that appears, quit the rolling. The sum includes $k$!!!

Comment: Doesn't it related with the negative binomial distribution?

Comment: When you say "until at least $k$ is gotten", does that mean until a sum of previous rolls is at least $k$ or that an individual roll is at least $k$?

Comment: An individual roll is at least $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that any roll is greater than or equal to $k$ is 
$$
\frac{13-k}{12}
$$
so the expected number of rolls until a roll of $k$ or greater is 
$$
\frac{12}{13-k}.
$$
All but the last one of these rolls is less than $k$, so the sum of those rolls has an expected value of 
$$
\left( \frac{12}{13-k} -1 \right) \frac{1+ (k-1)}{2}.
$$
Add to this the expected value of the final roll
$$
\frac{k+12}{2}
$$
and so the expectation of the sum is
$$
\left( \frac{12}{13-k} -1 \right) \frac{1+ (k-1)}{2} + \frac{k+12}{2} = \frac{78}{13-k}.
$$

Comment: I am wondering that the value we want is simply the sum of both expectations?

Comment: Yes, we can use the additivity of expectation here.

Comment: Isn't it a little strange that you both get the same answer even though you claim to be answering different questions?

Comment: Didier edited later.

Comment: And now I've edited my answer since Didier is now answering the right question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=12$ denote the number of faces. If the first roll is $i\geqslant k$, $X=i$. If the first roll is $i\lt k$, $X=i+X'$ where $X'$ is distributed like $X$. Hence,
$$
\mathrm E(X)=\frac1n\sum_{i\geqslant k}i+\frac1n\sum_{i\lt k}\left(i+\mathrm E(X)\right)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^ni+\frac1n\mathrm E(X)\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}1,
$$
that is,
$$
n\mathrm E(X)=\frac{n(n+1)}2+(k-1)\mathrm E(X),
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm E(X)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2(n-k+1)}=\frac{78}{13-k}.
$$

Comment: the sum includes last rolling.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on $k$?